# DNS Zone File: Can a A-record also have individual TTL when there is already a default TTL at the top of the file?

Tags: dns

The default TTL ($TTL) is set at the head of the zone file.
Individual resource records do not have TTL.

```
$TTL 86400 ;default TTL (1 day)
@ IN SOA ns1.xx.xx.cc. admin.xx.xx.cc. (
2022031800 ; serial yyyymmdd+
3H ; refresh
15M ; retry
1W ; expire
12H ) ; minimum
IN NS ns1.xx.xx.cc.
IN NS dns2.xx.xx.cc.
....
www IN A m.m.m.m1  ;this one is being moved outside 
www1 IN A m.m.m.m2
www2 IN A m.m.m.m3
...
```

m.m.m.m is the IP address of the current server.

The website [www.xx.xx.cc](http://www.xx.xx.cc) is being moved to an external, rental server. All the other subdomains (www1.xx.xx.cc, www2.xx.xx.cc, etc.) will have no change.

The rental server helpdesk tells me I need to change A-record for that resource (www1.xx.xx.cc), which I can do.

I want to minimize disruption after the dns entry change,
so I want to add TTL for that A-record, while keeping the default for all others.

It it possible?
I am afraid to try because I have no knowledge about DNS and I might break things.

So in short,
assuming "n.n.n.n" is the new IP address (of the hosting server),
can I change current A-record
from
"www IN A m.m.m.m1"
to
"www 300 IN A n.n.n.n"? (5 minutes),
while still keeping the default TTL (86400) for all other records?

Thank you for reading and replying!

---

It may be possible:
[TTL values for external DNS records](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227287/ttl-values-for-external-dns-records)

The writer says:
"The default is set for 24 hours and I have individual TTL values set for each individual record."

I would like to hear confirmation or denial or something in between.

Answer (score 1):

You asked, *can a DNS 'A' record have an individual TTL when there is already a default TTL at the top of the file?*

Yes it can.

```
dig hour.roaima.co.uk | grep -F 1.1.1.1
hour.roaima.co.uk.      3600    IN      A       1.1.1.1

dig minute.roaima.co.uk | grep -F 1.1.1.1
minute.roaima.co.uk.    60      IN      A       1.1.1.1
```

Extract from `bind` zone configuration file

```
; https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/696925/100397
minute          60      A       1.1.1.1
hour            3600    A       1.1.1.1
```